# Need advice on adding in-app purchases to a nursing edtech app after initial approval on iOS Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I recently had my nursing edtech application approved on the iOS Store after facing multiple rejections due to the "1.4.1 medical advice" guideline, even though my app is purely educational and doesn't offer diagnoses. To address this, I hid all the courses except one, and that helped me get the approval.

Now, I want to add in-app purchases for all the other courses in my app. It seems like I need to get approval for each individual in-app purchase. Has anyone faced a similar situation? How can I ensure that my app doesn't get rejected again during the in-app purchase review process? Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!